# Multiprocessing in python to speed up functions

Tags: python, windows, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am confused with Python multiprocessing.

I am trying to speed up a function which process strings from a database but I must have misunderstood how multiprocessing works because the function takes longer when given to a pool of workers than with “normal processing”.

Here an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
from time import clock, time
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

from random import choice


def foo(x):
    TupWerteMany = []
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
         TupWerte = []
          s = list(x[i][3])
          NewValue = choice(s)+choice(s)+choice(s)+choice(s)
          TupWerte.append(NewValue)
          TupWerte = tuple(TupWerte)

          TupWerteMany.append(TupWerte)
     return TupWerteMany



 if __name__ == '__main__':
     start_time = time()
     List = [(u'1', u'aa', u'Jacob', u'Emily'),
        (u'2', u'bb', u'Ethan', u'Kayla')]
     List1 = List*1000000

     # METHOD 1 : NORMAL (takes 20 seconds) 
     x2 = foo(List1)
     print x2[1:3]

     # METHOD 2 : APPLY_ASYNC (takes 28 seconds)
     #    pool = Pool(4)
     #    Werte = pool.apply_async(foo, args=(List1,))
     #    x2 = Werte.get()
     #    print '--------'
     #    print x2[1:3]
     #    print '--------'

     # METHOD 3: MAP (!! DOES NOT WORK !!)

     #    pool = Pool(4)
     #    Werte = pool.map(foo, args=(List1,))
     #    x2 = Werte.get()
     #    print '--------'
     #    print x2[1:3]
     #    print '--------'


     print 'Time Elaspse: ', time() - start_time
```

My questions:

1. Why does apply_async takes longer than the “normal way” ?
2. What I am doing wrong with map?
3. Does it makes sense to speed up such tasks with multiprocessing at all?
4. Finally: after all I have read here, I am wondering if multiprocessing in python works on windows at all ?

Comment: (1) has been addressed many times, the short story is that concurrency is not a magic go-faster pixie dust, it has overhead and is also limited by processor count and how much resources the OS can give away. I'd go search a link but these things are quite hard to search for.

Comment: Thanks Delnan. Please trust that I searched extensively before asking the question. I understand your point but hope that someone out there may have a "concrete" answer to this particular case.

Comment: @user1043144: How does the time change when you vary the number of processes in the pool?

Comment: actually no difference. I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: The reason your `map` doesn't work is that you have the arguments wrong; there is no `args` argument. It would be `pool.map(foo, List1)` (just like the bultin `map`), but `foo` actually wants a list. You should either change `foo` to just the inner-loop part or do something like `pool.map(foo, (List1[i:i+10] for i in xrange(len(List1), None, None, 10))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your first problem is that there is no actual parallelism happening in `foo(x)`, you are passing the entire list to the function once.

1)
The idea of a process pool is to have many processes doing computations on separate bits of some data.

```
 # METHOD 2 : APPLY_ASYNC
 jobs = 4
 size = len(List1)
 pool = Pool(4)
 results = []
 # split the list into 4 equally sized chunks and submit those to the pool
 heads = range(size/jobs, size, size/jobs) + [size]
 tails = range(0,size,size/jobs)
 for tail,head in zip(tails, heads):
      werte = pool.apply_async(foo, args=(List1[tail:head],))
      results.append(werte)

 pool.close()
 pool.join() # wait for the pool to be done

 for result in results:
      werte = result.get() # get the return value from the sub jobs
```

This will only give you an actual speedup if the time it takes to process each chunk is greater than the time it takes to launch the process, in the case of four processes and four jobs to be done, of course these dynamics change if you've got 4 processes and 100 jobs to be done. Remember that you are creating a completely new python interpreter four times, this isn't free.

2) The problem you have with map is that it applies `foo` to EVERY element in `List1` in a separate process, this will take quite a while. So if you're pool has 4 processes `map` will pop an item of the list four times and send it to a process to be dealt with - wait for process to finish - pop some more stuff of the list - wait for the process to finish. This makes sense only if processing a single item takes a long time, like for instance if every item is a file name pointing to a one gigabyte text file. But as it stands map will just take a single string of the list and pass it to `foo` where as `apply_async` takes a slice of the list. Try the following code

```
def foo(thing):
    print thing

map(foo, ['a','b','c','d'])
```

That's the built-in python map and will run a single process, but the idea is exactly the same for the multiprocess version.

Added as per J.F.Sebastian's comment: You can however use the `chunksize` argument to `map` to specify an approximate size of for each chunk.

```
pool.map(foo, List1, chunksize=size/jobs)
```

I don't know though if there is a problem with `map` on Windows as I don't have one available for testing.

3) yes, given that your problem is big enough to justify forking out new python interpreters

4) can't give you a definitive answer on that as it depends on the number of cores/processors etc. but in general it should be fine on Windows.

Comment: Also, for smaller set sof operations that don't cost much, the overhead in setting up the multiprocessing stuff is greater than any speedups you get

Comment: thanks. This is just an example I created. My actual problem involves huge data sets.

Comment: `pool.map` doesn't launch a new process each time; it reuses the four (or however many) created by the `Pool`. It does pickle/unpickle the arguments each time, however.

Comment: I never said it launches a new process

Comment: @user1043144 if by huge you mean HUUGEE!! you might want to consider not loading in the data in the main process but in `foo`, you could possibly use `mmap` to only load that part of the file(s) that is actually needed. Loading and passing around all that data will also cost you, so depending on what huge is there could be some significant savings had there as well.

Comment: COOL ! for List*2000000, your code runs in 7.5 sec with 4 workers and 6.2 with 8 workers. in "normal" it runs in 16 seconds. THANKS A LOT. Minor edit: args=(List1[tail:head],)). I have not understood the problem with map :-(

Comment: @MattiLyra Sorry, misread part of your answer before, but "This will only give you an actual speedup if the time it takes to process each chunk is greater than the time it takes to launch the process." is somewhat misleading in that respect.

Comment: Point taken, added some clarification on that. Cheers

Comment: You might try a `chunksize` argument for `pool.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

On question (2) 
With the guidance of Dougal and Matti, I figured out what's went wrong. 
The original foo function processes a list of lists, while map requires a function to process single elements.

The new function should be

```
def foo2 (x):
    TupWerte = []
    s = list(x[3])
    NewValue = choice(s)+choice(s)+choice(s)+choice(s)
    TupWerte.append(NewValue)
    TupWerte = tuple(TupWerte)
    return TupWerte
```

## and the block to call it :

```
jobs = 4
size = len(List1)
pool = Pool()
#Werte = pool.map(foo2, List1, chunksize=size/jobs)
Werte = pool.map(foo2, List1)
pool.close()
print Werte[1:3]
```

Thanks to all of you who helped me understand this.

**Results of all methods:**
for List * 2 Mio records: normal 13.3 seconds , parallel with async: 7.5 seconds, parallel with with map with chuncksize : 7.3, without chunksize 5.2 seconds

Answer (score -2):

Here's a generic multiprocessing template if you are interested.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker(x):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print "x= %s, x squared = %s" % (x, x*x)
    return x*x

def apply_async():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args = (i, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    apply_async()
```

And the output looks like this:

```
x= 0, x squared = 0
x= 1, x squared = 1
x= 2, x squared = 4
x= 3, x squared = 9
x= 4, x squared = 16
x= 6, x squared = 36
x= 5, x squared = 25
x= 7, x squared = 49
x= 8, x squared = 64
x= 10, x squared = 100
x= 11, x squared = 121
x= 9, x squared = 81
x= 12, x squared = 144
```

As you can see, the numbers are not in order, as they are being executed asynchronously.

Comment: How is this related to the question? A generic `mp` template can be found in the docs as well?

Comment: b/c they weren't even using the multiprocessing the correct way in the  question. This is a proper way to do it, the poster can use it to rewrite their function correctly for gods sake.