# Can I speed up performance by applying functions to an item in a data object with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

**Disclaimer:** I have gone through loads of `multiprocessing` answers on SO and also documents and either the questions were really old (Python 3.X has made tons of improvements since) or did not find a clear answer. If I might have missed out something relevant do point me in the right direction.

I started with a simple function that I defined as below in my folder module since I am running of Jupyter Notebook and it seems that due to conflicts, you can only run `multiprocessing` on an imported function:

```
def f(a):
    return a * 100
```

Built some test data and ran some test:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, Array, Queue
from time import time

from modules.test import *

li = [i for i in range(1000000)]
```

**List comprehension: Really Fast**

```
start = time()
tests = [f(i) for i in li]
print(f'Total time {time() - start} s')
>> Total time 0.154066801071167 s
```

**Answer of an SO example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116004/multiprocessing-in-python-to-speed-up-functions): 11 seconds or so**

```
start = time()

results = []
if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobs = 4
    size = len(li)

    heads = list(range(size//jobs, size, size//jobs)) + [size]
    tails = range(0,size,size//jobs)

    pool = Pool(4)
    for tail,head in zip(tails, heads):
        r = pool.apply_async(f, args=(li[tail:head],))
        results.append(r)

    pool.close()
    pool.join() # wait for the pool to be done

print(f'Total time {time() - start} s')
>>Total time 11.087551593780518 s
```

And there is `Process` which I do not know whether will be applicable to the example above. I am unfamiliar with `multiprocessing` but do understand that there is some overhead in creating new instances and what not, but as the data grows larger it should justify the overhead.

My question is, with the current performances in Python 3.x, is using `multiprocessing` in running similar operations to the above still relevant or something one should even attempt. And if it is, how can they be applied in parallelizing the workload.

Most of the examples I have read and understand are used for web scraping when there is an actual idle time in one process receiving information and it makes sense to parallelize but how would want approach it if you are running computations of something like a list or dictionary.

Comment: Why in the world are you doing all that list-processing first? Just that will take longer than using the list-comprehension. It seems to just be recreating `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, so just use that instead. Anyway, your calculation here is *very fast*, and your data is pretty small, so try using a calculation that isn't so trivial, because just sending the data over the wire will destroy any gains made by the parallelism

Comment: Again that is an example, what I am more concern is that if the data scales much higher, would it then make sense to use `multiprocessing.Pool` or any of its methods. What do you mean by over the wire?

Comment: There is inter-process communication required. Literally, pickling and sending to another process. The cost of that inter-process communication is always higher than the cost of your very trivial function. You could try to use a shared-array which would require more code, but it wouldn't require IPC

Comment: I know it is trivial for the example, assume a more complex function. Would you be able to provide an example for a shared-array. Trivial being said, having almost 10 times worst performance was not something I expected.

Comment: The ten-times worse performance is totally a consequence of all that inefficient stuff you are doing *before* you even use the multiprocessing Pool. Using your exact example, except using multiprocessing.Pool.map, I get a much more modest difference (although still slower). But yes, when the actual calculation is much more time consuming, multiprocessing gets you real gains. It's just that your trivial function has no hope of being slower than the time it takes to pickle the data, send it to the process, run the function, then pickle it again, and send it back to the main process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your example is not performing well is because you are doing two totally different things.

In your list comprehension, you are *mapping `f` onto each element of `li`*.

In the second case, you are splitting your `li` list into `jobs` chunks and then apply your functon `job`s times onto each of those chunks. And now, in `f`, `n * 100` takes a chunk about a quarter the size of your original list, and multiplies it by 100, i.e., it uses the sequence-repitition operator, so creates *a new list 100-times the size of the chunk*:

```
>>> chunk = [1,2,3]
>>> chunk * 10
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

So basically, you are comparing apples to oranges.

However, multiprocessing already comes with an out-of-the box mapping utility. Here is a better comparison, a script called foo.py:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    return x * 100

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = list(range(1000000))

    start = time.time()
    [f(i) for i in data]
    stop = time.time()
    print(f"List comprehension took {stop - start} seconds")

    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        result = pool.map(f, data)
    stop = time.time()
    print(f"Pool.map took {stop - start} seconds")
```

Now, here's some actual performance results:

```
(py37) Juans-MBP:test_mp juan$ python foo.py
List comprehension took 0.14193987846374512 seconds
Pool.map took 0.2513458728790283 seconds
(py37) Juans-MBP:test_mp juan$
```

For this very trivial function, the cost of the inter-process communication will always be higher than the cost of calculating the function serially. So you won't see any gains from multiprocessing. However, a much less trivial function *can* see gains from multiprocessing.

Here's a trivial example, I simply sleep for a microsecond before multiplying:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(x):
    time.sleep(0.000001)
    return x * 100

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = list(range(1000000))

    start = time.time()
    [f(i) for i in data]
    stop = time.time()
    print(f"List comprehension took {stop - start} seconds")

    start = time.time()
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        result = pool.map(f, data)
    stop = time.time()
    print(f"Pool.map took {stop - start} seconds")
```

And now, you see gains commensurate with the number of processes:

```
(py37) Juans-MBP:test_mp juan$ python foo.py
List comprehension took 13.175776720046997 seconds
Pool.map took 3.1484851837158203 seconds
```

Note, on my machine, a single multiplication takes orders of magnitude less time than a microsecond (about 10 *nanoseconds*):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('100*3', number=int(1e6))*1e-6
1.1292944999993892e-08
```

Comment: Thanks, while I already understood that there will be overheads, the question highlights *My question is, with the current performances in Python 3.x, is using multiprocessing in running similar operations to the above still relevant or something one should even attempt. And if it is, how can they be applied in parallelizing the workload.*. Will see if there are any noticeable differences for a more complex operation.

Comment: @BernardL I addressed that. I added  a trivial example in an edit, check it out.

Comment: Thanks. So from what I understand, it does have improvements but only to justify the overhead. I guess the example was TOO trivial in that sense. Haha. Would `Process` have a different outcome on it you think?

Comment: Also does that mean the answer in my linked answer seems to be pointing at a less effective solution, seeing that the pool is recreated for every view?

Comment: @BernardL I've edited my question with an explanation for why you are seeing bad performance with that linked answer. You are actually doing two different things. See the edit.

Comment: Right, got it. I totally overlooked that I'm not mapping the function onto the items but I was multiplying the whole list. Thanks!

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, got around in running your example, which is weird, are you sure you got those times when you included sleep? My machine pretty much matches most of your times except `foo.py` that included sleep which the list comprehension itself took ~1300 seconds and `Pool.map`, ~300 seconds, still an improvement but hoping not to mislead others when they try the code as well.

Comment: @BernardL I don't understand your concern? Isn't that the same results I got? Are you sure you mean 1300 *seconds*? I'm running that exact code and getting ~13s and ~3s. Check the decimal points on the call to sleep. Alternatively, sleep can work differently depending on your os, and might not have the same level of precision on, say, Windows.

Comment: Ah yes, yeah its weird and I am on windows, I am taking out the `mp` part atm, and the sleep function is not adding up, I did some math around it and the sleep function was supposed to add the runtime by a factor of 10. But for because of the os, it does not work that way. Thanks again man.