# Why is concurrent futures slower than my loop?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

Hey guys I wanna speed up my code with multiprocessing by using concurrent futures. I wrote some code to test and understand concurrent futures and to simulate my case. But somehow is the concurrent futures method slower than the loop..

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

A = range(0,100000)
B = range(1000,20000)
SumList = []
DiffList = []
SumList2 = []
DiffList2 = []

def Funktion(items):
    A, B = items
    Sum = A + B
    Diff = A-B
    return(Sum, Diff)

def Funktion2(A, B):
    Sum = A+B
    Diff = A-B
    return(Sum, Diff)

start1 = time.time()
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for Sum, Diff in executor.map(Funktion, zip(A, B)):

        SumList.append(Sum)
        DiffList.append(Diff)


stop1 = time.time()
time1 = stop1 - start1
print('With Executor=', time1)

start2 = time.time()
i = 0
for x in A:
    Sum, Diff = Funktion2(A[i], B[i])
    SumList2.append(Sum)
    DiffList2.append(Diff)

stop2 = time.time()
time2 = stop2 - start2
print('Normal= ', time2)
```

The result is:
With Executor= 5.426360130310059
Normal=  0.08866691589355469

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Because the cost of the `multiprocessing` overhead is much higher than the cost of the function you are trying to parellelize. Note, you have to *copy the data* (literally `pickle` it) and send it across the wire

Comment: As to why it's slower, read my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218164/can-i-speed-up-performance-by-applying-functions-to-an-item-in-a-data-object-wit/53218842#53218842) about the overhead of inter-process communication. simply put, the function you are trying to parallelize is too trivial to ever gain anything using `multiprocessing`

Comment: Parallelism is not a magic incantation that you cast to make code faster.