# map threads with itertools

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-itertools

For example I am having such code

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
#combinations is from itertools which makes combinations from 3 elements of array
def build_func(i):
    print(i)
operators=[1,2,3,4,5]
size=3
pool = ThreadPool(5)
pool.map(build_func, itertools.combinations(operators,size))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

I want to make threads from generator results but it is really slow and dont works correct. 
If I just use

```
for i in itertools.combinations(operators,size):
    build_func(i)
```

It works faster, so threads are used incorrect. Is there way to make threads usefull?

Comment: Could you be more specific about "dont works correct"? It runs without error on my machine.

Comment: changed  with example

Comment: Why do you think that because your for-loop faster, that the threads used were incorrect? Do you automatically assume that a threaded program will work faster? That is not the case. Especially on CPython with the GIL. Even without the GIL, given the scale of your example here, the thread-pool probably has way overhead than any gains you would get from parallelism, again, even assuming (incorrectly) that you are getting that.

Comment: So there is no way to make itertools faster in such example?

Comment: Such a small trivial example? Almost certainly not using `multiprocessing`. There are many trade-offs. `multiprocessing` isn't magic you sprinkle onto your code to make things run faster. See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218164/can-i-speed-up-performance-by-applying-functions-to-an-item-in-a-data-object-wit/53218842#53218842 In your particular case, you are not using multiple *processes*, but multiple *threads*. But CPython has a global interpreter lock, so only one thread can run in the python process at a time anyway...